# Volley library dosent connect to server in some devices

Tags: java, android, android-volley, httpurlconnection

in first i'm use `Httpurlconnection` and have same issue(Dosent find my Url in server in some devices and other device conncet easy) and  i think bug e Httpurlconnection and i decide use Volley and same issue exist when use that
Error:

```
com.android.volley.VolleyError:java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Volley Code :

```
StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, uri,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.i("HOOOO", response);
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject(response);
                        int success = Integer.parseInt(jsonobj.getString("success"));
                        String msg = jsonobj.getString("message");
                        check(Flag,success,msg,pass,email);
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        Snackbar snackbar1 = Snackbar.make(Mainlayout,e.toString(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                        snackbar1.show();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Log.i("Error Respone", error.toString());
                    Snackbar snackbar1 = Snackbar.make(Mainlayout,error.toString(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                    snackbar1.show();

                }
            }
    ) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams()
        {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            if(Flag=="Insert") {
                params.put("email", email);
                params.put("fact", DeviseBrand);
                params.put("model", DeviseModel);
            }else if((Flag=="signin") ||(Flag=="update") ){
                params.put("email", email);
            }
            // the POST parameters:

            return params;
        }

    };
    postRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            9000,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(postRequest);
```

and my uri :

```
http://domain.com/App/Register.php
```

Post data and on server get with _Request[];

Comment: add all error stacktrace and part of code, where it happenes

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Volley is a very strong API, i don't think they could have such an issue, check your code maybe in some cases it doesn't initialize the object correctly.
I used Volley for more than 1 year and didn't had such issue.
1-check that you are using the latest release from [this link](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley).
2-put your code in question so we can check it with you, also the log could be helpful to trace the issue, also what is the device you are using ?

Comment: ok,i know that,but this error in some devices and is So Weird,Does the file i put on server should have special permission?

Comment: i don't think so, if file permission works on device it should work in any device. there is two cases could be happening with you:

Comment: 1- the Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(postRequest); could be the reason for the null check out this tutorial which they use singleton with volley.http://www.androidhive.info/2014/09/android-json-parsing-using-volley/

Comment: 2- Mobile devices case which is 'maybe' there is a network issue if you are using local network maybe trying to ping the server or host from the testing device could show you if it can reach the server.

Comment: emm ,this issue is on more than one phone and in some devices has error that im dosent reach thats!

Comment: mmm your code looks good although, can you post the console error log?

Comment: becuse my device work good , i ask to my firend get me he's phone and check ... i send all error and log As soon ! thank for respone ! ♥